# Outputting table rows from MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, rows

In PHP, I want to output table rows in a specific format, for every two mysql records like this.

So data being outputted would be 1,2,3,4,5,6 from the database but with a new row for each two numbers. What is the best way to do this?

```
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>6</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: While displaying in loop break line every 2 elements: `if ($loopIndex%2==0) echo '</tr><tr>';`

Comment: Tried googling but search terms were obviously off.. Just for an example of what I was after.. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            $i=1;
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
            {
                if ($i % 2 == 0)
                    echo '</td></tr>';
                $i++;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming your database query returns an array...

```
for($i=0; $i<count($array)/2; $i++) {
  echo "<tr><td>{$array[2*$i]}</td><td>{$array[2*$i+1]}</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: Wow, my bad. O_o `"{2*$i}"` doesn't work, `"{$array[2*$i]}"` does. Learned something new today...